# How to click on a <a> tag with a href=# using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to download a file from a website but am not able to interact with the download button.
The button is linked to the `<a>` tag with a `href=#`.

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
        <a class="btn btn-download" href="#" onclick="creditingRates.download();" style="display: block;">Download CSV</a>
    </div>
```

I have tried the following but non seemed to work.

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#')]"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn btn-download']/a[text()='Download CSV']))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to click the element you need to wait for element clickability, not just presence.
2. From the shared HTML I see it's the `a` element who has `class="btn btn-download"`, not a parent `div` element.
   I can't debug this, only to guess, so I'd try the following:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-download'][text()='Download CSV']"))).click()
```

Or maybe

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-download'][contains(,text(),'Download CSV')]"))).click()
```